# Как можно добавить в tkinter виджеты подобные тем которые представленны на илюстрации ниже? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, виджет

Как сделать виджет на tkinter подобный вот этому:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

искал в интернете но ничего не нашел, помогите пожалуйста, и можно ли так сделать вообще

Comment: https://www.delftstack.com/ru/tutorial/tkinter-tutorial/tkinter-combobox/

Comment: Спасибо щяс гляну